# How do I pass by reference in perl for hash values

Tags: perl, variables, hash, reference, subroutine

I have the following code, I wrote to truncate large values.

```
   sub truncate_large_email_tag
    {
      my($email_tag) = @_;
      my $size = length($email_tag);

    if ($size>5000) { 
        my $fragment = substr($email_tag,0,5000);
        $email_tag = $fragment;
        #log_it( "\n\Truncated Large Email tags\n\n") if $TRACE;
        }
```

and I am calling this subroutine using the call in another subroutine say

```
  sub do_something
   {
  #some code here # CFG_PASS is a hash

        $EMAIL{$tag}=$CFG_PASS{$typ}{$tag}{$where . '_DEFAULTS'}; #Email        
        #tag initialized here
        truncate_large_email_tag($EMAIL{$tag});
        }
```

But when I check $EMAIL{$tag} is still pointing to non-truncated value. am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl always passes by reference. The problem is that you didn't modify the parameter, but a variable you created in the function and into which you copied the argument (`my ($email_tag) = @_;`).

Change

```
my $fragment = substr($email_tag, 0, 5000);
$email_tag = $fragment;
```

to

```
my $fragment = substr($email_tag, 0, 5000);
$_[0] = $fragment;
```

or

```
$_[0] = substr($email_tag, 0, 5000);
```

or

```
$_[0] = substr($_[0], 0, 5000);
```

or

```
substr($_[0], 5000) = '';
```

---

So you end up with

```
sub truncate_inplace {
    substr($_[0], $_[1]) = ''
        if length($_[0]) > $_[1];
}

truncate_inplace($EMAIL{$tag}, 5000);
```

But why not just use

```
sub truncate {
    my ($s, $max_len) = @_
    return length($s) > $max_len ? substr($s, 0, $max_len) : $s;
}

$EMAIL{$tag} = truncate($EMAIL{$tag}, 5000);
```

Comment: Man, you guys are awesome... I will try the suggestions out ;)

Comment: +1 for the last snippet of code in this way you don't need to pass a reference to the key value at all just do the assignment

Comment: @bjackfly, you don't need to pass a reference in any of the seven versions. Doing so would actually be wrong!

Answer (score 2):

As you surmised, you are passing `$EMAIL{$tag}` by value, so your modifications get thrown away after the sub ends and the original is unchanged. There are two ways to do what you want.

Way one:

```
truncate_large_email_tag(\$EMAIL{$tag});
```

This passes a reference to `$EMAIL{$tag}` to the subroutine. Inside the sub, you'll need to dereference it to do your work:

```
my ( $email_tag_ref ) = @_;
my $email_tag = $$email_tag_ref;
```

That can be abbreviated as:

```
my $email_tag = ${ $_[0] };
```

Way two:

Take advantage of the fact that `@_` is special and *aliases* the calling parameters.

```
$_[0] = substr($email_tag,0,5000);
```

By assigning directly to `$_[0]`, you will alter the original parameter.

Personally, I prefer way one since it's more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

In perl, scalar arguments get passed by reference automatically, and that's what you have here.  You're not trying to pass the entire hash; you're only trying to modify one of the values in it.

You can modify the arguments to a subroutine call by assigning back to `@_`, like this:

```
sub truncate_large_email_tag
{
    my($email_tag) = @_;
    my $size = length($email_tag);

    if ($size>5000) { 
        my $fragment = substr($email_tag,0,5000);
        $email_tag = $fragment;
        #log_it( "\n\Truncated Large Email tags\n\n") if $TRACE;
    }

    $_[0] = $email_tag;  # modify argument in the caller
}
```

That said, it *is* usually clearer to send an explicit reference.  To do that, put a backslash in front of the argument when calling, and use an additional `$` to dereference in the callee:

```
sub truncate_large_email_tag
{
    my ($email_tag_ref) = @_;
    my $size = length($email_tag);

    if ($size>5000) { 
        my $fragment = substr($email_tag,0,5000);
        $$email_tag_ref = $fragment;
        #log_it( "\n\Truncated Large Email tags\n\n") if $TRACE;
    }
}
```

And then when you call it:

```
truncate_large_email_tag(\$EMAIL{$tag})
```